# Copying contents of a char array into another

Tags: c, arrays

How do I get the contents from one character buffer into another? For instance I have

```
char buffer[SMALLVALUE];
char new_buffer[BIGGERVALUE];
```

I'd like to copy the contents of `buffer` into `new_buffer`. What's the shortest way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#include <string.h>

memcpy(new_buffer, buffer, sizeof buffer);
```

Comment: Okay let's say I do this and now my new_buffer has stuff in it, then my OLD buffer gets more stuff in it and I need to copy it over again. Will `memcpy` work like normal string concatenation?

Comment: void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);

The memcpy() function copies n bytes from memory area src to memory area dest.  The memory areas should not overlap.  Use memmove(3) if the memory areas do overlap. (From memcpy manpage).

Comment: Will memmove be necessary if my old buffer is like `buffer[32]` and my new buffer is `new_buffer[1000]` and my strings are well under that 1000 size?

Comment: @febreezey: If these are actually strings, i.e., NULL terminated and not simply an arbitrary sequence of bytes, then use `strcpy`; that's what it's there for.

Comment: I see, so that will be better because I'm only using strings, and it will be helpful if I'm just trying to add more to the buffer as opposed to overwriting what is already in it.